# How to prevent asynchronous in ajax using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I can't explain my questions in word, i'll post my code. Then, try to explain it there.

```
$('#all').on('change', function(){ //ONCHANGE RADIOBUTTON, THERE ARE #bdo, #cash also.

$.ajax({
    type:"GET",
    url: "phpfunction.php?getFromTo=all",
    dataType:"json",
    success: function(data){
        $('#slctfrom').find('option').remove().end();
        $('#slctto').find('option').remove().end();
        $('#slctyr').find('option').remove().end();
        $.each(data, function(index, item) {
            if (item.dt != "") {
                $('#slctfrom').append('<option value='+item.dt+'>'+item.dt+'</option>');
                $('#slctto').append('<option value='+item.dt+'>'+item.dt+'</option>');
                $('#slctyr').append('<option value='+item.dt+'>'+item.dt+'</option>');
            }
        });
    }
});

var fyy = document.getElementById("slctfrom").value;
var tyy = document.getElementById("slctto").value;
var yr = document.getElementById("slctyr").value;
var type = document.getElementById("slcttype").value;
var graph;
if (document.getElementById("column").checked) {
    graph = "column";
} else if (document.getElementById("line").checked) {
    graph = "line";
} else if (document.getElementById("area").checked) {
    graph = "area";
} else {
    graph = "pie";
}
if (tyy < fyy) {
    document.getElementById("errormsg").innerHTML = "Error: The 'To' value must be greater than or equal the 'From' value.";
} else {
    chart("all", graph, fyy, tyy, yr, type); //FUNCTION CHART.
}
});
```

I want to execute my ajax first and then it executes my onchange because sometimes my options get null, and then if I try to change the checked in radiobutton which is #bdo not included in my code since it is the same as #all, it will be nulled forever, it doesn't get the new value

Comment: backend didn't sent messages out if your item is null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your code in the success/error callback.

```
$('#all').on('change', function() { //ONCHANGE RADIOBUTTON, THERE ARE #bdo, #cash also.

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "phpfunction.php?getFromTo=all",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {

            ajaxCallback();

            $('#slctfrom').find('option').remove().end();
            $('#slctto').find('option').remove().end();
            $('#slctyr').find('option').remove().end();
            $.each(data, function(index, item) {
                if (item.dt != "") {
                    $('#slctfrom').append('<option value=' + item.dt + '>' + item.dt + '</option>');
                    $('#slctto').append('<option value=' + item.dt + '>' + item.dt + '</option>');
                    $('#slctyr').append('<option value=' + item.dt + '>' + item.dt + '</option>');
                }
            });
        },
        error: function() {
            ajaxCallback();
        }
    });


    function ajaxCallback() {
        var fyy = document.getElementById("slctfrom").value;
        var tyy = document.getElementById("slctto").value;
        var yr = document.getElementById("slctyr").value;
        var type = document.getElementById("slcttype").value;
        var graph;
        if (document.getElementById("column").checked) {
            graph = "column";
        } else if (document.getElementById("line").checked) {
            graph = "line";
        } else if (document.getElementById("area").checked) {
            graph = "area";
        } else {
            graph = "pie";
        }
        if (tyy < fyy) {
            document.getElementById("errormsg").innerHTML = "Error: The 'To' value must be greater than or equal the 'From' value.";
        } else {
            chart("all", graph, fyy, tyy, yr, type); //FUNCTION CHART.
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Sorry it worked, but i put the ajaxCallback() after $.each().. thank you sir.

Answer (score 0):

Use async:false as an option in the Ajax call

Comment: Synchronous ajax requests are being deprecated.  This is not a good answer.

Comment: Sir, it worked but I'm getting an error in my console.log. The error is : Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/. What does this mean?

Comment: I'd say it's a correct answer to the question asked by the OP, but the deprecation should be explained: https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#sync-warning

Comment: Is it safe to use async:false?

Comment: The problem with async:false is that your ui will freeze until a response is received or the request times out.

Comment: Using it on Chrome you will see a warning in the console "Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/."

Answer (score 0):

I think you can put the ajax call to jQuery's ready event. because the url always the same. And use [$.getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON) for short.

And if the ajax call is long, you can add loading mask to prevent use fire the change event.

```
$(function(){
    $.getJSON('phpfunction.php?getFromTo=all', function(data){
        $('#slctfrom, #slctto, #slctyr').empty();
        if(!data){
            return;
        }

        $.each(data, function(index, item){
             if (item.dt != "") {
              $('#slctfrom, #slctto, #slctyr').append('<option value='+item.dt+'>'+item.dt+'</option>');
           }    
        });
    });
});

$('#all').on('change', function(){ //ONCHANGE RADIOBUTTON, THERE ARE #bdo, #cash also.

    var fyy = $("#slctfrom").val();  //may be this is better
    var tyy = document.getElementById("slctto").value;
    var yr = document.getElementById("slctyr").value;
    var type = document.getElementById("slcttype").value;
    var graph;
    if (document.getElementById("column").checked) {   
            graph = "column";
    } else if (document.getElementById("line").checked) {
            graph = "line";
    } else if (document.getElementById("area").checked) {
            graph = "area";
    } else {
            graph = "pie";
    }
    if (tyy < fyy) {
            document.getElementById("errormsg").innerHTML = "Error: The 'To' value must be greater than or equal the 'From' value.";
    } else {
            chart("all", graph, fyy, tyy, yr, type); //FUNCTION CHART.
    }
});
```